# Stack Overflow mentioned on NPR's "Wait, Wait... Don't Tell Me" and NY Times

Tags: discussion, publicity

Wow — stackoverflow.com was cited by ["Wait, Wait"](http://www.npr.org/programs/wait-wait-dont-tell-me/) as a reference this weekend.  NY Times [picked it up](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/12/18/opinion/sunday/wait-wait-dont-tell-me.html), too:

> It was a big week in science. Physicists at the Large Hadron Collider say they may have found the “God particle,” and one computer scientist came up with a new way of finding:
>
> A. Waldo
> B. The meaning of life
> C. Someone to kiss on New Year’s Eve
> D. His one missing sock

Answer:

> (A) In a write-up on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/), a computer scientist used the imaging software Mathematica to come up with an algorithm that can find Waldo in any image. This development will have serious implications for United States surveillance operations if terrorists ever start wearing stripy sweaters and red stocking caps.

Comment: And the SO post: [How do I find Waldo with Mathematica?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479058/how-do-i-find-waldo-with-mathematica)

Comment: It appears that it wasn't actually used in the show, just on the [blog](http://www.npr.org/blogs/waitwait/2011/12/18/143865340/the-wait-wait-snack-pack).

Comment: uh oh... Not sure if that's a serious article or not, but it exemplifies the classic disconnect between science and news reporting. As my comment there says, it works for _that_ image, not _any_ image, as is claimed in the article. Nevertheless, that is a good answer.

Comment: If you know the show, it's not serious.  The point is that Stackoverflow is mentioned, not the rigor of the citation or the generality of the answer.

Comment: If you'd stopped right after "D. His one missing sock" you could have let someone answer it.  Then it would have fit into the format, right?

Comment: Actually, I didn't include the question or the answer.  Someone else added it for me.

Comment: Actually, *you* didn't include a lot of detail at all! ;-)

Comment: TIL we have a spoiler tag which only reveals text on hover. How odd.

Comment: lol this post reminded me of the time I felt like an idiot for asking what "NPR" meant in Programmers.SE beta days because all I could think of was "National Public Radio"

Comment: Interesting...SO is mentioned in the big public and the only thing I *really* care about is "Please stop calling Mathematica an 'imaging software'".