# Questions meant not to be answered

Tags: feature-request

I was exploring the "Unanswered" tab trying to find an unanswered question I could answer.  I think there should be a mechanism to sort out the Questions that shouldn't have answers so they don't appear there.  Questions such as [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) and [Stack Overflow mentioned on NPR's "Wait, Wait... Don't Tell Me" and NY Times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116401/stack-overflow-mentioned-on-nprs-wait-wait-dont-tell-me-and-ny-times) are wonderful to have as a reference point - but don't need an answer.

Comment: Why not just filter out the "discussion" tag?

Comment: I appreciate all the answers about search queries.  However, not all Stack Exchange members are programmers or other professionals who routinely do search queries.  Risking more down votes, I still think there should be a better way to find unanswered questions that are actually looking for answers.

Comment: How do you magically determine what is "looking for answers" and what is not?

Comment: Perhaps a specific tag could be used

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is refine your search queries slightly and you'll be able to browse through posts which have no answers at all. For example -

- [[unicorns] answers:0](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bunicorns%5D+answers%3A0)

This search query will return questions with the [unicorns](/questions/tagged/unicorns) tag that have zero answers. There are many additional conditions that you can add to your queries. They are listed on the [search help page](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=).

There is also some confusion about the title of that "unanswered" tab. The posts listed there are not necessarily unanswered - but rather do not contain an "accepted answer".

Answer (score 2):

You could always perform a search yourself using something like

```
answers:0 -[faq]
```

That won't get rid of the second questions you've linked, but the validity of that one is debatable anyway. It probably only remains because this is Meta.

Answer (score 1):

If this type of question were on the main site then I'd be concerned.

However, as it's Meta, these types of question are fine.

The meta sites bend (if not break) the normal rules of Stack Exchange in all sorts of ways - including the type of "question" that is allowed.

You can use Meta for announcements etc.

Comment: Was this a mis-post or something? Doesn't really seem related to this post...

Comment: @Lix Nah, I think this addresses the *"Questions that shouldn't have answers are fine for Meta"* part just fine.